# How change views exposed filter drop down format?

Tags: 7, views

I'm working on a D7 site where I am trying to implement a simple view of a custom content type. I want to have a drop-down select list of taxonomy terms to be able to filter the content by. At the moment, I just seem to have a box with the taxonomy terms in it. They filter the content appropriately when selected, but the UI seems bad to me and I'm not sure how to change it. It has the same UI implementation whether or use Better Exposed Filters or not.
[image]

What I'd like to implement is just a scrollable drop down select list but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears currently that you have the select box as multi-select. Do you want the user to choose 1+ values or only 1 value? If you want it as a dropdown in the more classic sense, then limit that to one value. BEF would allow you to modify some of the aspects of the select box, as well as allow you choose to use checkboxes instead of a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Make set a height on your select list and set `overflow-y` to the height you want it at.

Something along these lines:

```
select.form-select {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 20px;
}
```